# Creating an appropriate Sparse Matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, sparse-arrays

i have a 6$\times$6 matrix of the form

```
mat = SparseArray[{Band[{2, 1}, {3, 2}] -> 1., 
Band[{1, 1}] -> {a, b, a}, Band[{1, 2}, {2, 3}] -> 1., 
Band[{4, 4}] -> {-a, -b, -a}, Band[{5, 4}, {6, 5}] -> -1, 
Band[{4, 5}, {5, 6}] -> -1, Band[{2, 5}, {2, 5}] -> c, 
Band[{5, 2}, {5, 2}] -> -c}, 6] // MatrixForm
```

I want to create a 18 $\times$ 18 analog of the above.
The nonzero elements should appear at the appropriate places as they appear in this one. e.g. `m[2,5]` will go to `m[3,8]` for a 10$\times$10 version.
How to do it so that I don't have to manually place elements at the appropriate place? Infact, there are four 3$\times$3 matrices put side by side in my above example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite hard to abstract the desired pattern from the simple, low-dimensional example.

Anyways, your goals can be achieved by expressing the positions in terms of matrix size; in your case, you seem to to want matrices of size $2 \, (2 k + 1)$, $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

What I believe to have understood is that you want a `c` in the center of both the lower-left and upper-right blocks. The rest is subject to quite some free interpretation. Anyways, this should provide you with enough  ideas to set up your matrices as desired.

```
k = 3;
n = 2 k + 1;
mat = SparseArray[
   {
    Band[{1, 1}] -> Join[{a}, ConstantArray[b, n - 2], {a}],
    Band[{2, 1}] -> ConstantArray[1, 2 k],
    Band[{1, 2}] -> ConstantArray[1, 2 k],
    Band[{n + 1, n + 1}] -> Join[{a}, ConstantArray[b, n - 2], {a}],
    Band[{n + 1, n + 2}] -> ConstantArray[-1, 2 k],
    Band[{n + 2, n + 1}] -> ConstantArray[-1, 2 k],
    {n + k + 1, k + 1} -> c,
    {k + 1, n + k + 1} -> c
    },
   {2 n , 2 n}
   ];
mat // MatrixForm
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccccccccccc}
>  a & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  1 & b & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 1 & b & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 1 & b & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & c & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & b & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & b & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & a & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & b & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & b & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & c & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & b & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & b & -1 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & b & -1 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & a \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

Comment: Many thanks. This is exactly what was needed :-)

Comment: Just one more thing: Will `With[{a=2,b=5,k=3,
n=2k+1},
mat = SparseArray[....]` work? It seems to return errors when I want to assign values to `a`, and `b` with this method. Any workaround this problem?

Comment: Try `With[{k = 3}, 
 With[{a = 2, b = 5, n = 2 k + 1}, mat = SparseArray[ ...]]]` instead.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks :-)

Comment: You're welcome.